# Shimming Highcharts in Webpack

Tags: javascript, highcharts, webpack

I have got this `webpack.config.js` definition:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/app",

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Scripts"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    entry: ["./app.ts", "angular", "angular-ui-router", "jquery", path.join(__dirname, "vendor", "highcharts.src.js"), path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/angular-local-storage/dist", "angular-local-storage.js")],

    stats: "minimal",

    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
    },

    plugins: [
        // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            "Highcharts": "imports?this=>global!exports?global.Highcharts",
        })
    ],

    devtool: "source-map",

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "raw", exclude: exclusionRegexs },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css", exclude: exclusionRegexs },
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ng-annotate!ts-loader", exclude: exclusionRegexs }
        ]
        /*preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, // include .js files
                exclude: /node_modules/, // exclude any and all files in the node_modules folder
                loader: "jshint-loader"
            }
        ]*/
    }
};
```

this line is supposed to export highcharts and then import highcharts directly onto the window object, which is what I want to do, but it is not quite there. There is an [example](https://gist.github.com/Couto/b29676dd1ab8714a818f) which demonstrates how to do it.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "Highcharts": "imports?this=>global!exports?global.Highcharts",
})
```

In the highcharts src is:

```
Highcharts = win.Highcharts = win.Highcharts ? error(16, true) : {};
```

So evidently it is being put onto the window.

I assume it's go something to do with the `entry` stuff, there is a path in that array which points directly to the correct place where highcharts is defined, and it is bundling it correctly.

I think somewhere I haven't linked `ProvidePlugin` highcharts entry with the source entry?

The current error I'm getting from the webpack build output is:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'exports'

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having trouble importing highcharts+exporting into my webpack es6 project as well.

Comment: nope, i think the provide plugin is the way to go!